# Как настроить git, чтобы ничего не передавалось ни на какой сервер?

Tags: git

Начал разбираться с git, хочу его использовать локально (т.е. на одном ПК).

Как его так настроить, чтобы ничего не передавалось ни на какой сервер?

Answer (score 5):

Ничего не нужно делать. Просто установить GIT и пользоваться. Не путайте с github. Начинайте [изучать документацию.](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Answer (score 3):

Ничего настраивать не надо. И пока вы не выполните определенные команды ничего передаваться не будет. В этом и состоит, основная особенность гита. Что в принципе нет централизованного сервера. Каждая локальная версия независима. Вы можете синхранизировать и сливать ветки гита хранящиеся в разных местах между собой, но это опционально.

Answer (score 1):

Никаких настроек не требуется, вы можете спокойно фиксировать свой изменения в созданном репозитории.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -a -m "Init"
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220765/using-git-locally